# Determine whether $ \{ a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} \mid a,b,c\in\mathbb Z\}$ is an abelian group

Tags: group-theory

Let $R = \left\{ a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} \mid a,b,c \text{ are integers}\right\}$. Consider $(R; +,*)$, with the usual addition and multiplication

**Question:** Determine whether $(R,+)$ is an abelian group or not.

To show this, do we only need to prove $(R,+)$ is commutative and nothing else?

This is what I did: Let $$ x = a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4}$$ and $$y = d + e \sqrt[3]{2} + f\sqrt[3]{4},$$

and then I proved $x+y = y+x$. Is that all in this case? Don't we need to prove the other properties of a group (btw I am new to group theory so details would be much appreciated).

And, if we were to show $(R,+,*)$ is a commutative ring, is it okay to choose some random values or do we need to work it out and show?

Comment: You would also need to show it has a zero element and additive inverses, and closure under addition, and associativity. (These are easy for this example.)

Comment: You have to show:
(i) associativity
(ii) $\exists e \in R : e + a = a = a + e \forall a \in R$
(iii) $a \in R \rightarrow -a \in R$
(iv) + is closed $(a+b) \in R \forall a,b \in R$
and (v) commutative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$R$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore the simplest approach is to prove that $R$ is a *sub*group of the commutative group $\mathbb{R}$ (with addition). To do this, check that $R$ contains zero and is closed under addition and opposites. Addition is automatically commutative in $R$ because it is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Right you are. But alternatively, one may choose simply to show that the set is closed under subtraction.