# Let $R = \{ a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} \mid a,b,c\in\mathbb Z\}$ is R an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111130/determine-whether-a-b-sqrt32-c-sqrt34-mid-a-b-c-in-mathbb-z), but I am still confused with the answers I got. I am not asking to do the problem again as I've already got that part. My question is: Is it necessary to go over all the properties of a group to show something is an abelian or just showing for commutativity would suffice. I mean I can prove all those properties, but that'd be time consuming on a test if not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Our numbers are all real numbers, so if we assume the commutativity of real number addition, that property is inherited by our smaller group, as is associativity.

Comment: All you hace to prove  is it's stable for addition, opposite and contains 0 . Actually you show it's an abelian group by showing it's a subgroup of $\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ***generally*** it doesn't suffice and the following is true:

> To show that a set $H$ with operation "$+$" is an abelian group, you have to verify **all** group axioms **and** show that $H$ is commutative regarding "$+$".

Now, often you can take a shortcut. But even in this case it doesn't suffice just to show commutativity of $H$ regarding "$+$".

Say $H \subset G$ and $H$ not empty, and you know that $G$ is a group, then to show that $H$ is a group is much easier: you just have to prove that $H$ is closed under "$+$" and contains inverses of all its elements. Or more concretely,
$$a, b \in H \Rightarrow a+b \in H \text{ and } -a \in H\,.$$
You automatically know it must have a neutral element, because for any $a\in H$ just use $a - a = 0$, also $H$ inherits the property "associativity" from $G$.

*So in this case, you don't have to prove all group axioms for $H$.*

And then you show that "$+$" is commutative:
$$\text{ For all } a, b \in H: a+b = b+a\, .$$
If in addition you know that $G$ is not just *some* group, but an *abelian* group, it gets even easier. Then you can skip the proof for the commutativity of "$+$", because if "$+$" is already commutative for the bigger group $G$ then the same must clearly be true for $H$, which is just a subset of $G$.